# Acrescentar um char em um ponteiro de char em C/C++

Tags: c, c++, string, ponteiro, char

Preciso acrescentar um `char` em um ponteiro de `char`. Por exemplo: tenho um ponteiro de `char` chamado nome, que recebe "log", após o processo, quero que ele fique "log1".

Tentei implementar assim, porém não deu certo.

```
 bool trocarNome(char *nome){
     nome +='1';
     cout<<nome;
  }
```

Comment: Existe alguma razão para não usar a classe `string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em C, você pode usar a função strncat, ficaria assim:

```
#include <string.h>
...
bool trocarNome(char *nome){
    strncat(nome, "1", 1);
}
```

Comment: Estou usando strncat(nome, "1", 1); porque do jeito que você escreveu estava dando erro de sintaxe, porém agora entra em um loop infinito e cracha o programa.

Comment: Sim, desculpe, eu copiei o seu código e esqueci q strncat recebe uma string, não char. Sobre o erro, é difícil dizer, depende de como está o resto do seu código, mas você pode verificar se o ponteiro "nome" ainda tem espaço alocado para mais caracteres.

Comment: Reforço o comentário do @JJoao de que convinha corrigir o `'1'` na sua solução. Ganha o meu +1 só depois de fazê-lo. :)

Comment: Na verdade, é tão crítico, que deixei um "-1" aqui - só o strncat, sem espaço para mais caracteres não vai funcionar,

Comment: Corrigida a solução ;-)

Comment: Ok, obrigado por corrigir. Ganhou o meu +1 como prometido. Aproveito para avisar o @jsbueno (quem sabe ele tira o -1 dele depois da correção?). :)

Comment: Ah  - não - trocar 'por " é praticamente um erro de digitação - o maior problema é não ter nenhum comentário - nem código lidando com a situação -  de não se ter espaço para uma string maior com o uso do strncat.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do Júlio funciona e está tecnicamente correta. Mas o código está escrito em C++. E o recomendado nesta linguagem é usar o tipo `string` sempre que possível. Se não houver motivos para evitá-lo, seria melhor fazer assim:

```
bool trocarNome(string nome) {
    nome += '1';
    cout << nome;
    return true;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fzlmJi). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tstxhbsz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/Concat.cpp).